# Windows Phone 8 Restore In App Purchase on different device

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase

My app is for Windows Phone 8. I don't get in app purchases on other device configured with same account. On the start of app I am trying to restore purchases. Below is the snippet.

```
var licenses = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses;
if (licenses.Count == 0)
{
   Logger.Debug("Licenses for MS server is zero.");
   return;
}                 
else
{
 string str = string.Empty;
 foreach (var item in licenses)                  
 {                 
     str = str + item.Value.ProductId + "  ";
 }                   
  Logger.Debug("PURCHSE_STORE First call to sync. Product ids found :" + str);
}
```

I have published app on Windows Phone Store (in hidden mode) and created In App Product PRODUCT_1 with price zero. I have downloaded app on my two test devices DEVICE A and DEVICE B which are configured with same account. Now I made an In App Purchase on DEVICE A for PRODUCT_1 . After some time when I launched app on DEVICE A and DEVICE B, I expect to see PRODUCT_1 in log of both devices. But its only appearing in log of DEVICE A on which I made purchase not on DEVICE B.

Products are 'Consumable' because we are working on  WP 8.0 and we need to create monthly and annual passes. As I understand, in WP 8.0 we can't specify duration of Durables. That's why we are using consumables. We are not fulfilling the product till it expires. For example if user has purchased monthly pass we will give him access for a month then we will send fulfillment request so that he can buy again. Every time user try to access restricted content we check if he has already purchased respective pass.

Please help me in properly restoring in app purchases.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you haven't fulfilled the product, indicating that you are testing this with 'Consumable' products, not Durables.

The Windows Phone Store does not actually support restoration of Consumables, you're expected to track how many "coins" or "gems" the user has purchased through your own means. See Managing App Updates and Versioning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206949(v=vs.105).aspx

If you can use a Durable IAP though everything should work fine and the product will appear under ProductLicenses on other phones w/ the same Microsoft account.